# Find the empirical probability that two successive births will be girls

Tags: probability

The following simulation was conducted to simulate birth of boys and girls:

BGBGB  GGBBG  GGBGB  BBGBG  BGGBB  BGGGB  GBGBB

Find the empirical probability that two successive births will be girls. Hows the answer 6/34 ?

Answer (score 3):

There are 34 consecutive pairs in the 35 births. There are 6 pairs of GG.

$BGBGB \underline{GG} BB \underline{GGG} BGBBBGBGB \underline{GG} BBB \underline{GGG}BGBGBB$

I have underlined the places where $GG$ occurs, which contribute to the pair of $GG$. Note that $GGG$ contribute 2 pairs (the first two and the last 2).

Empirical probability = $\frac{ \mbox{ # successes} } { \mbox{ # outcomes} } = \frac{6}{34} $.

Comment: @ Calvin so that can include GG as well as GBG but not the GGG right?

Comment: No. They must be consecutive.

Comment: So tha answer should be 5?

Comment: @MethodManX No, count it. there are 6 times that $GG$ appears. Note that $GGG$ means that $GG$ appears twice.